# Expected unqualified-id before '&' token

Tags: c++

(extremely) inexperienced in C++ but I've been getting along ok until now and this has me stumped. I'm unsure if I've included enough code to diagnose this but I believe it's syntax and might be figured out from the following. I'm getting the error mentioned from the line below:

```
#pragma once
#include "cinder/Vector.h"
#include "cinder/Color.h"
#include <vector>

class Predator {
public:
    Predator();
    Predator( ci::Vec3f pos, ci::Vec3f vel );
    void pullToCenter( const ci::Vec3f &center );
    void update( bool flatten, const ci::Channel32f &channel ); // <- error's here
    void limitSpeed();
    void draw();
    void drawTail();
    void addNeighborPos( ci::Vec3f pos );
```

And can't spot anything wrong? I've googled the error and it usually seems syntax related but can't see how it relates here. The line giving trouble is actually used in a previous class and doesn't throw any errors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
#include "cinder/Channel.h"
```

http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.2/_channel_8h.html

Comment: That was exactly what was needed. It was the fact that another class got the same code to work without including Channel directly that threw me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you don't have the right `#include` for `Channel32f`.

Comment: It's always something so simple. I was actually going to write that all the includes were correct, but rather than being stubborn I pasted all the includes from the previous class where the same line worked.

It doesn't make sense that one of them would make it compile correctly but it did. I'm baffled. Will figure it out now.... thankyou for the push!

Comment: Ah, it was including the header of another class (A) that happened to, itself, contain an include the needed class (B) that threw me. I didn't see an obvious inclusion missing.

Comment: "I pasted all the includes from the previous class where the same line worked." That is cargo cult programming. Resist the temptation! The temptation is admittedly rather strong with a huge language such as C++. When you feel the urge to do cargo cult programming, step back and figure out what is going on.